# Passing parameter to each column of datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-datatables

In my Laravel 5.6 application, I try to pass a `$id` variable from my route to each single column of my datatable.

My code:

```php
 public function getVendorslistChange($id){
    try {
        return Datatables::of($this->purchaseRepository->getVendorListData(),$id)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($vendor,$id) {
                return \Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['PurchaseController@postChangeVendor',$id], 'class' => 'form']) . '
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $vendor->id . '" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose" class="btn center-block" />
                ' . \Form::close();
            })
            ->make(true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->redirectWithErrors($e);
    }
}
```

this part `$this->purchaseRepository->getVendorListData()` will return the following:

```php
public function getVendorListData(){
    $this->vendors = Vendor::Select(
        array(
            'vendors.id',
            'vendors.company_name'
        ))
        ->where('vendors.company_id',return_company_id())
        ->where('status','Active')->get()
    ;
    return $this->vendors;
}
```

But there is error said, the `$id` cannot be passed to the `addColumn`.

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PurchaseController::App\Http\Controllers{closure}(), 1 passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel-project/american_dunnage/vendor/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/Utilities/Helper.php on line 64 and exactly 2 expected

What is the proper way to pass parameter like this to each column of the datatable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't just add parameters to vendor functions if they don't support them. For example, when you call `Datatables::of()`, the source code shows that it only expects one parameter. So even though you pass the extra `$id` variable, that `$id` won't be passed to the callback function that you give to `addColumn()`. That's why you see that error about too few arguments being passed in.

https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/blob/8.0/src/DataTables.php#L33

Something like this might work. Notice how I'm telling the callback to `use` the `$id` instead of trying to pass it directly into the function call:

```
public function getVendorslistChange($id){
    try {
        return Datatables::of($this->purchaseRepository->getVendorListData())
            ->addColumn('action', function ($vendor) use ($id) {
                return \Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => ['PurchaseController@postChangeVendor',$id], 'class' => 'form']) . '
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $vendor->id . '" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose" class="btn center-block" />
                ' . \Form::close();
            })
            ->make(true);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->redirectWithErrors($e);
    }
}
```

Check out example 3 in the docs to see how to manage anonymous function scopes:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: thanks a lot. i was stuck for a day with this issue.